# I can't get rid of duplicates in products view

Tags: commerce

I tried everything. I reduced the number of fields.
I set the Query settings to distinct.
Product: Variations (variations:delta) is also set to 0.

When I search by SKU I get duplicates. SKU Search is exposed filter for admins.

This is the generated query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "commerce_product_field_data"."created" AS "commerce_product_field_data_created", "commerce_product_field_data"."product_id" AS "product_id", "commerce_product_variation_field_data_commerce_product__variations"."variation_id" AS "commerce_product_variation_field_data_commerce_product__vari", "taxonomy_term_field_data_commerce_product__field_catalog"."tid" AS "taxonomy_term_field_data_commerce_product__field_catalog_tid", DATE_FORMAT((DATE_ADD('19700101', INTERVAL commerce_product_field_data.created SECOND) + INTERVAL 7200 SECOND), '%Y%m%d') AS "commerce_product_field_data_created_day"
FROM
{commerce_product_field_data} "commerce_product_field_data"
LEFT JOIN {commerce_product__variations} "commerce_product__variations" ON commerce_product_field_data.product_id = commerce_product__variations.entity_id AND commerce_product__variations.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {commerce_product_variation_field_data} "commerce_product_variation_field_data_commerce_product__variations" ON commerce_product__variations.variations_target_id = commerce_product_variation_field_data_commerce_product__variations.variation_id
LEFT JOIN {commerce_product__field_catalog} "commerce_product__field_catalog" ON commerce_product_field_data.product_id = commerce_product__field_catalog.entity_id AND commerce_product__field_catalog.deleted = '0'
INNER JOIN {taxonomy_term_field_data} "taxonomy_term_field_data_commerce_product__field_catalog" ON commerce_product__field_catalog.field_catalog_target_id = taxonomy_term_field_data_commerce_product__field_catalog.tid
WHERE ("commerce_product_field_data"."status" = '1') AND ("commerce_product__variations"."delta" = '0')
ORDER BY "commerce_product_field_data_created_day" DESC
LIMIT 500 OFFSET 0
```

I don't know how else to ask this question. I did lots of research. Nothing helps. The duplicates are keep on showing up.

Comment: and this is the screenshot of view https://snipboard.io/L7Ybk5.jpg

Comment: https://snipboard.io/l32gqp.jpg is the second part of view

Comment: I want to give us admins many options to filter out products...search by SKU, title, select only specific categories etc. But each time there are annoying duplicates in view results.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell how you've configured the View to add DISTINCT to the query, but just looking at the query, it's clear that this will return *every* distinct combination of far too many variable items. Even the fact that created timestamp is in there is likely enough to always return everything ... unless literally every combination of product + variation + catalog term + etc. was created on the same day.

At the end of the day, this isn't a "remove duplicates from Views results" problem so much as a "how to configure a better View" problem. I'm not sure that's appropriate for Drupal Answers, tbh.

Comment: I would just want to list products, category, SKU, title and price without duplicates. Is this possible? You are saying that Query Distinct is the problem? I disable Distinct Query under advanced view and when I search for SKU I get each product listed twice again

Comment: I'm saying the way the DISTINCT clause is being added to the query is the problem. Can you satisfy your criteria by making this a View of product variations, perhaps? I don't see in your list any information that must come from the product itself, and even if you did need a field from the parent product, there is a single value reference field from the variation -> product you could join through. No duplicates that way.